# Class field naming vs method parameter naming

Tags: java, standards

What is considered best practice when it comes to naming class fields vs. method parameters in the same class?

For example, if I have a field named `transactionType`, should I also name the parameter in my setter method `transactionType` and just refer to the field using `this.transactionType`?

I am not asking for an opinion, I just want to know if this is acceptable or would it be considered confusing since there are two uses of the same name (though obviously different in scopes).

Comment: to emphasize, I am curious what the standard would be. not personal preferences. thanks :)

Comment: Look for Java naming conventions.

Comment: Hm, this is a very good question! Personally I prefer to use the same names, makes it clear to what and why the parameter is there for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is standard Java idiom to use the same name for the parameter as for the field, in both setter methods and constructors.  Your IDE will probably propose such parameter names when you ask it to create a setter or parameterized constructor.

Within such methods, you must use `this.` to specify the field; the unadorned name refers to the parameter.  `transactionType` means the parameter while `this.transactionType` means the field.

Comment: I would add that in this case he should use `this.`

Comment: Cool this was exactly what I was looking for. As long as most people don't find it confusing I would prefer to name this way because it makes it so much easier to understand which parameter relates to which field. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using the same identifier and `this.` is acceptable and commonly done. I've done it with others in large projects and it works fine, at least when the project uses static analysis tools (such as IntelliJ inspections) to catch the occasional conflict.

There is no standard; no-one is in charge of Java code style. Use what works well for you. Even popular code standards usually have a dumb thing or two in them. You be the judge.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It's good practice to use a meaningful parameter name rather than short and not understandable name.

It would be better if you are using the same name as the instance field name to make it more clear.

By using this you can **benefit of Auto JavaDoc** that uses the parameters names.

Comment: Your point is fine, but that's not what the questioner is asking. They're just asking about using the same identifier for fields and method parameters (regardless of its other qualities).

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Please correct me if I am wrong. OP is asking why use same name for fields and method parameters?

Comment: They're asking whether that's an acceptable practice. Looks like your answer addresses that; so far so good. Your first sentence is addressing something else, though.